# Bootable USB drive, but with files in sub folder?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, flash

I created a bootable USB drive which works as expected, but it creates a bunch of obscure files cluttering up the main storage space of the flash drive. Will it still work if I put these boot-files in a sub folder?

Also, is there a way to put multiple bootable images on 1 flash drive but be able to select which one when in the BIOS? For example, if I wanted to create a flash drive bootable version of Ubuntu and Acronis Rescue Media, 1 one physical flash drive, would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move the `obscure files` to another location as the bootloader and subsequent programs that execute will look for it in the location they currently are in.

As for multi-boot take a look at [YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator (Windows)](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: Thanks for the software link! That's what I went with, it also solved my first issue. YUMI puts the ISOs in a sub folder, not directly on the drive so it keeps the initial drive space as organized as possible.